# Passing fixed arguments in method function without using eval

Tags: javascript, methods

**Scenario**

I have a "main object" `System` containing a method called `System.Test`. It accepts, for example, three arguments `System.Test(id, a, b)`.

Now I have many objects (`User[1]`, `User[2]`, `User[3]`...) where I also want the `.Test` method available. However, the `id` argument it passes is unique to each `User[X]` object and should be fixed, for example, if I call `User[1].Test(a, b)` it should automatically map to `System.Test(1, a, b)`.

**What I've done so far**

The amount of `User[X]` objects is variable. Suppose I am looping through each of them and I have their ID in a variable called `id` (=1, 2, 3...). I tried using this code within the loop.

```
User[X].Test = function(a, b) {
    return System.Test(X, a, b);
}
```

However, this does not work as expected. At the moment User[X].Test() is called, it simply passes to the `System.Test` function **the last key X in the loop** and not the X unique to each User[X] object.

**The ugly way - the problem**

The solution seems fairly straightforward if I could use *eval*.

```
eval("User[X].Test = function(a, b) { return System.Test(" + X + ", a, b); }");
```

Now, this could work as a hack. But the `.Test` was just one example, and I can't imagine using dozens of *eval* calls as soon as the amount of methods increases. Although the only variable that is injected in *eval* is `X` (and I can guarantee that `X` is generated internally and totally secure - no risk of malicious code execution) - the use of eval creeps me. Is there a better way to do this that I don't know of? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind` for partial application:

```
User[X].Test = System.Test.bind(null, X);
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! What if I want to use something similar to .bind() to **append** arguments? Or is it too much trouble and I should simply unify everything to prepending the `X`?

Comment: Note that some old browsers(e.g. IE8) do not have `Function.prototype.bind()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility

Comment: You could just wrap it in an anonymous function that takes more parameters and calls the other function.

Comment: @Mics Thanks for the heads-up. Project's targeting Chrome nightlies only though, so I'm lucky! :)